# I want to print all Armstrong number between a given range irrespective of the no. of digits in the number entered by user in Java

Tags: java

I have written this program but can't find the error in this to get desired result.
I have given the range of the number by user input and want to find armstrong numbers between them.

Input: Enter the range to print armstrong number between them.
100
10000

```
Expected Output: Armstrong Number between 100 and 10000: 
                153  370  371  407  1634  8208  9474


My Program Output: Enter the Range to Print Armstrong Number between Them
                   100
                   10000
                   There is no Armstrong Number between 100 and 10000
```

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArmstrongList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Range to Print Armstrong Number between Them");
        int start = scanner.nextInt();
        int end = scanner.nextInt();
        int cubeSum = 0, digit, counter = 0;
        for(int i = start; i < end; i++){
        int count = 0;
        int num = i;
        while(num!=0) {        //Count no. of digits in the Number
            num /= 10;
            ++count;
        }
        
        int temp = i;
        while(temp!=0) {
            digit = temp % 10;
            cubeSum = cubeSum + (int)(Math.pow(digit , count));
            temp/=10;
        }
        if(cubeSum == i) {
            System.out.println(i + " is an Armstrong number ");
            if(counter == 0){
                System.out.println("Armstrong Number between " + start + " and " + end + ": ");
            }
            System.out.println(i + "  ");
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if(counter == 0) {
        System.out.println("There is no Armstrong Number between " + start + " and " + end);
    }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Comment: what is the error you are facing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't reset `cubeSum` to zero on each iteration.

There is no benefit in declaring variables outside the loop. Variables don't actually cost anything to declare inside a loop(*): they don't even exist at runtime. At runtime, it is just "some place in memory" where a value is stored and read from. So, declare them in the tightest scope possible, in order to avoid accidentally reusing value from previous computations.

Move the declaration of the `cubeSum` into the for loop, ideally immediately before the while loop where it is incremented (while you're at it, declare `digit` inside the loop too):

```
    int cubeSum = 0;
    while(temp!=0) {
        int digit = temp % 10;
        cubeSum = cubeSum + (int)(Math.pow(digit , count));
        temp/=10;
    }
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/3hZhL5)

[Learn to use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

An even better approach could be to declare methods to calculate the cube sum (and count, similarly):

```
int cubeSum(int i, int count) {
  int cubeSum = 0;
  while(i!=0) {
    int digit = i % 10;
    cubeSum = cubeSum + (int)(Math.pow(digit , count));
    i/=10;
  }
  return cubeSubm;
}
```

This scopes the variables even more tightly, so you don't see the intermediate computations, and get a much clearer main method, with effectively final variables:

```
int count = count(num);
int cubeSum = cubeSum(i, count);
if (cubeSum == i) {
  // Print that it's an Armstrong number.
}
```

---

(*) The *value* assigned to a variable might cost something, if you create a `new Whatever()` on each iteration, or evaluate some expensive function; but assigning a constant primitive has almost zero cost.